# Get the last know value for a specific reference in inconsistent timeline

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get records from the `stats` table and if there is no data for the specific day and reference get the latest known value for a given ref.

stats table:

```
| ref | date     | views |
| --- | -------- | ----- |
| 1   |2022-01-01|1      |
| 2   |2022-01-01|1      |
| 1   |2022-01-02|2      |
| 2   |2022-01-02|1      |
| 1   |2022-01-03|2      |
| 1   |2022-01-04|3      |
| 2   |2022-01-04|3      |
```

As you see above there the record for ref 2 at 2022-01-03 is missing.
Now I want to sum views for those records and group them by the `ref` column and since there is one missing record for ref 2 the value for the summation should be taken from the latest record (2022-01-02).

I have also the posts table:

```
| id  | title     |
| --- | --------- |
| 1   |title no. 1|
| 2   |title no. 2|
```

Also, I have to create a timeline from the oldest stat to the current date.
What do I have is:

```SQL
WITH RECURSIVE timeline (
    date
) AS (
    SELECT
        MIN(date)
    FROM
        stats
UNION ALL
SELECT
    DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 day)
FROM
    timeline
WHERE (timeline.date < CURRENT_DATE),

posts_days AS (
    SELECT timeline.date, posts.id
    FROM
        posts
    CROSS JOIN timeline
),

view_stats AS (
    SELECT posts_days.date, posts_days.id, stats.views
    FROM
        posts_days
    LEFT JOIN stats ON  (stats.ref = posts_days.id and stats.date = posts_days.date)
)

SELECT
    view_stats.date, SUM(view_stats.views) AS views
--  ,SUM(prev_stats.views) AS prev_views, 
FROM view_stats
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT id, (view_stats.views) as views, date FROM view_stats GROUP BY id, date
    ) as prev_stats on prev_stats.date = (
      SELECT date FROM view_stats s1 
        WHERE s1.date < view_stats.date and s1.id = view_stats.id ORDER BY date desc limit 1
    ) and prev_stats.id = view_stats.id
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date
```

But it obviously behaves in the wrong way.
I would be appreciated any tips on how to solve this one.